# how to use .htaccess to convert EVERYTHING except index.php to a parameter

Tags: .htaccess

Is there way to use .htaccess as follow

mydomain.com
redirects to
mydomain.com/index.php

and

mydomain.com/everything except index.php
redirects to
mydomain.com/index.php?u=everything except index.php

In other words, convert everything (directories, sub-directories, pages and so on) to a simple string param to pass through the variable u to index.php

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To send absolutely everything to index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Note that this would also send requests for images, css, javascript, etc to index.php. Since this probably isn't what you want, this one may be more appropriate:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?u=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This one would send all requests for files and directories that don't exist to index.php. Note this would mean that anything in your htdocs folder would be accessible by it's url. So this would rely on your htdocs folder being mostly empty.